# Adding an ease to a simple slide / jquery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, easing

i finally found the perfect, simple jquery code for my new page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
</script>
```

I would like to add the easing function and time, like in this code:

```
  $('#mypage-info').slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {
      // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

My guess would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv")..slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {

    });

});
</script>
```

but i get an error...

Comment: Check this http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations

Comment: What's your question? You seem to have the parts you need. Are you including jQuery UI or a plugin that handles easing?

Comment: You seem to have a syntax error. You have 2 `.` on this line `$(".slidingDiv")..slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {`. It should be `$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the double `.` you have.  You have a syntax error.  Change:

```
$(".slidingDiv")..slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {
```

to this:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!! But I'm still having a problem with an error <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function () {

    }); <---! Dreamweaver tells me this is an syntaxerror?!

});
</script>

Comment: this works: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3AuVN/)  this doesn't: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t32my/4/) ...